# how to convert data from sql query to excel

Tags: excel

i have sql query result like

```
 **ITEMID**                     **Str**
4 NITE       7891109372876
4 NITEK 
4 NITEICE GREY/BLACK     7891266811096
4 
4 NITEWHITE/BLACK        7890557462726
AERO GRA
AERO GRAPHICBLACK        7891266733404
AERO GRAPHICBLACK        7891266733411\
```

if i copied this result in excel the str format is changed like this

```
ITEMID                  Str
4 NITEBLACK
4 NITE  7.89
 GRAPHICBLACK   
AERO GRAPHICBLACK       7.89127E+12
sults in excel
```

Comment: You already do. There is no string format involved, this is numeric data. Just change the format of your Excel column to the format you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on the cell --> format cells --> Choose a suitable category.
Hope it helps ;)